# Unexpected Error when paying with PayPal

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal

Im trying to set a paypal payment in my app, but it doesnt seem to work:

Ive already got my app approved, and got a live API key, but this happens when Im trying to log into some paypal account (it isnt mine because you cant pay yourself):

[image: paypal error]

The Logcat doesnt show anything useful. It acts as if nothing happned.

my code:

```
    PayPal ppObj;
    CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment;

public void pay(View v) {
    PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
    newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("10.00"));
    newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
    newPayment.setRecipient("myEmail@gmail.com");
    newPayment.setMerchantName("name");
    Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
    this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
}
```

inside OnCreate:

```
ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "**APP-LIVE-API-KEY**", PayPal.ENV_LIVE);
```

`android:onClick="pay"` calls to `pay` from the layout file. I dont use a special paypal button.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did u solved ur issue?

Comment: No, Its still happening. @Monica

Comment: is it working properly in sandbox environment?

Comment: No.. Same error! @Monica

Answer (score 0):

Paypal state that should have premiere or business account

Comment: Please give a reference link.